# .Net SvcUtil: attributes must be optional

Tags: .net, xsd, attributes, code-generation, svcutil.exe

I'm trying to generate C# code classes with SvcUtil.exe instead of Xsd.exe. The latter is giving me some problems.

Command line:

```
SvcUtil.exe myschema.xsd /dconly /ser:XmlSerializer
```

Several SvcUtil problems are described and solved here:
http://blog.shutupandcode.net/?p=761

One problem I can't solve is this one: *Error: Type 'DatafieldDescription' in namespace '' cannot be imported. Attributes must be optional and from namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Seri
alization/'. Either change the schema so that the types can map to data contract types or use ImportXmlType or use a different serializer.*
'

I changed

```
<xs:attribute name="Order" use="required">
```

to

```
<xs:attribute name="Order" use="optional">
```

and

```
<xs:attribute name="Order">
```

But the error remains. Is it possible to use attributes, or do I have to delete them all (in that case, this excercition is over)?

Answer (score 6):

The answer, and a possible solution, can be found here:
[MSDN: Importing Schema to Generate Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702680%28VS.90%29.aspx)

Specific:
*The XsdDataContractImporter supports a limited subset of the schema. If **unsupported schema constructs** are present (**for example, XML attributes**), the import attempt fails with an exception. However, **setting the ImportXmlType  property to true extends the range of schema supported**. When set to true, the XsdDataContractImporter  generates types that implement the IXmlSerializable  interface. This enables direct access to the XML representation of these types.*

As in:

```
SvcUtil.exe myschema.xsd /dconly /ser:XmlSerializer /importXmlTypes
```

Sadly enough, this will result in this kind of code:

```
private System.Xml.XmlNode[] nodesField;
```

Regards,
Michel

Comment: +1: helped me figure out a problem I was having with `XMLSchemaSet.Compile()` ...